# How to embed Haskell in a batch file (hash-bang runhaskell for Windows)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, haskell, cmd, shebang

On a UNIX-like system with GHC installed, I can create an file with the following contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
main = putStrLn "Hello, I am a UNIX script file."
```

Make the file executable, and this executes the given Haskell code.

How do I do the equivalent in a Windows .bat file?

Preferably, no extra files are created, no environment variables are set, it also works if the batch file is accessed using a UNC path or a path containing spaces, the Haskell namespace is not polluted, and a reasonable behavior results if the Haskell code contains errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much trial and error, this turns out to be possible.  I have designed the following:

```
@(set /p =-- < nul & type "%~f0") | runhaskell & exit /b
main = putStrLn "Hello, I am a Windows batch file."
```

The only disadvantage of this mechanism is that error messages contain the name of a temp file created by (something called by) `runhaskell`.

Here is a full explanation of how this works:

- `set /p =-- < nul` outputs `--` (and two irrelevant spaces) not followed by a newline.  This works like this:

  - `set /p ANSWER=Please enter answer:` prints `Please enter answer:` without a newline, waits for user input, and puts that in environment variable `ANSWER`.
  - `< nul` acts as if the user did not enter anything.
  - As an (undocumented?) special case, the environment variable name can be left out, and then no environment variable is set.
- `"%~f0"` is the name of the current batch file.
- Therefore `set /p =-- < nul & type "%~f0"` outputs the current batch file, but with the first line commented out (when interpreted as Haskell code).
- We pipe this into `runhaskell`, which (undocumentedly?) interprets its stdin as non-literal (!) Haskell code.

  - Like in the UNIX version in the question, this assumes that `runhaskell` is on the current `PATH`.
- Finally, `exit` makes sure that everything after the first line is not seen by the Windows batch file interpreter, and `exit /b` makes sure that we only exit this script, not any surrounding `cmd.exe` shell.
- And the leading `@` makes sure that all this gibberish is not `echo`ed when running this script.

(I have not found a way to do the same for literate Haskell code; but I don't have a need for that currently.)

Answer (score 4):

Simply create under your PATH

```
C:\my-tools-path>copy con --.bat
runhaskell %1
^Z
```

To create your auto-executable haskell program write some like

```
-- "%~f0"
main = putStrLn "Merry Christmas!"
```

No errors, no temp files, ...

;)

(You can add your program args changing

```
runhaskell %1 %2 ...
```

and

```
-- "%~f0" %1 %2 ...
```

)

Comment: +1 for the very nice idea, but I'll accept my own answer since I want to have a single-file solution, so without the additional `--.bat` file.